# Automatically counting rows based on two changing criterion

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif, sumproduct

I have a dataset that has in it collections of 3 attributes from a wider pool of 16. I want to build a heat map that shows which attributes are more or less often connected to one another.

Currently my data is in the format (note this is a sample from a larger set of 70 rows):

[image: Image of the source data]

I would like to be able to automatically populate the following table:

[image: The table that needs populating]

Is there a way that I can automate this process in excel, instead of manually counting each time two attributes are mentioned in the same set of three? I've seen some examples using SUMPRODUCT, but these examples seem to required each column to have a specific type of data in, whereas in my example all 3 columns could contain any of the attributes.

Comment: Do you have Excel 365?

Comment: Yes. Office 365 is the software I’m using.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you, if you provide some sample data plus a table that shows your expected result. Reading [repro] will help you to improve your question Please use  [Markdown Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) as we can copy your data instead of typing them

Answer (score 2):

As you have Excel 365, you can use a [Lambda](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) with [Byrow](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/byrow-function-2e04c677-78c8-4e6b-8c10-a4602f2602bb) to get the row totals for the appearance of one word of a pair, then multiply by the totals for the other word to get the totals for the occurrence of both words. Add the resulting array to get the number of rows in which both words occur and drag down and across:

```
=SUM(BYROW($A$2:$C$6,LAMBDA(array,COUNTIF(array,$F3)))*BYROW($A$2:$C$6,LAMBDA(array,COUNTIF(array,G$2))))
```

[image]

Assumes an attribute can't occur more than once in a row.

As noted [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-byrow-function), Countif can be used in this situation although it takes a range rather than an array.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly extended/different approach than Tom Sharpe:

- It fills the whole matrix by making use of `MAKEARRAY` with horizontal and vertical attributes ranges as input.
- using double-negative to return the `COUNTIF`-conditions
- It excludes same-same-attributes (e.g. in my example a - a --> returns 0) ("last condition" `(INDEX(attrH,,c)<>INDEX(attrV,r)`)

```vb
=LET(attrH,B8:F8,
attrV,A9:A13,
MAKEARRAY(ROWS(attrV),COLUMNS(attrH),LAMBDA(r,c,
          SUM(BYROW(tblData,LAMBDA(row,
                      --(COUNTIF(row,INDEX(attrH,,c))*COUNTIF(row,INDEX(attrV,r))
                        * (INDEX(attrH,,c)<>INDEX(attrV,r)))))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Impressive! Should still work if you omit -- tho.